# How should I test my different rollup bundles

Tags: javascript, rollup

Let's say that I made 3 bundles of my library with my rollup config

- `esm`
- `cjs`
- `umd`

I want to try each of the bundles in their respective environment.

- How would I proceed ?
- Do you know any example of repositories that already implemented those tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it necessary? Usually I only do unit test of the source codes.
Anyway, the only difference is to use babel or not.

install

```
npm i @babel/register mocha
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

```
//package.json
{
//...
 "scripts":
    "test:es": "mocha test/index.esm.js --require @babel/register",
    "test:cjs": "mocha test/index.cjs.js",
    "test:umd": "mocha test/index.umd.js"
  }
}
```

"import/require" part are different in test files:

```
//test/index.esm.js
import xx from '../dist/xx.esm.js'
```

```
//test/index.cjs.js
const xx = require('../dist/xx.cjs.js')
```

```
//test/index.umd.js
const xx = require('../dist/xx.umd.js')
```

For umd you may also test it in browser environment. Just build a html file, include mocha.js, umd.js with <script> tag and runs it.